# How to fix TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) Error

Tags: python, tkinter, wand

I am trying to split the uploaded pdf file into images but i am getting error like take at least 2 arguments(1given).

I know this error is already asked but i confused to fix in my program.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from wand.image import Image
import os

from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
root =Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("pdf")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)
        label = Label(self,text="Upload a pdf file",font = ('Arial' , 25))
        label.pack()
        self.Label1=Label(self)
        self.Label1.pack()
        self.button = Button(self, text="Upload", command=self.load_file, fg="red", width=10).pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename()
        self.Label1.config(text=os.path.basename(fname), fg="blue")
        self.im = Image(filename=fname, resolution=200)
        for i, page in enumerate(im.sequence):
            with Image(page) as page_image:
                page_image.alpha_channel = False
                page_image.save(filename='page-%s.png' % i)

        print "suceSsfully"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Whenever i run this code ,i am getting this error.

> ```
> File "root.py", line 27, in load_file
>     self.im = Image(filename=fname, resolution=200)
> TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
> ```

Comment: Don't you see all the similar questions in the **Related** list on the right?

Comment: Yea I saw but i am confused with it.Please help me out

Comment: What line is the error happening on? What's the full error with traceback?

Comment: File "root.py", line 27, in load_file
    self.im = Image(filename=fname, resolution=200)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You need to pass another argument to `Frame.__init__(self)`.  See the examples in the documentation:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error / traceback to it.

Comment: I added the error in my question

Answer (score 2):

`Tkinter` has it's own `Image` class `Tkinter.Image`.
When you import all from Tkinter after import `wand.image.Image`, you start to use `Image` class from `Tkinter`.
You should import `Tkinter` as `import Tkinter as tk` and use it with `tk.class_name`, or explicit use `wand.image.Image` instead of `Image`.